# ListView not getting populated from the Adapter

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, google-books

This app is used to fetch the books as JSON using Google Books API and on research I also found that the JSON data is loading fine and the Book Title, Author is parsed correctly and I tested that using toasts. But the listView is not showing up even from setting the listView with the adapter. What must be the error? The app also doesn't crash making it little difficult to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance!

**Main Activity**

```
package com.praveent.booklisting;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String rootUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes";
    public String queryParameter = "q";
    Button search_button;
    EditText search_string;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        search_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        search_string = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_string);
        search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String query = search_string.getText().toString();
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
                    new BackgroundTask().execute(query);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please switch on the internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void populate(BookAdapter adapter){
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, JSONArray, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String query = strings[0];
            URL url = null;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(rootUrl).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(queryParameter, query).build();
            try {
                url = new URL(uri.toString());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String data = null;
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
                scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
                if(scanner.hasNext()){
                    data = scanner.next();
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            BookAdapter bookAdapter;
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            JSONObject jsonArrayObject = null;
            JSONObject volumeInfo = null;
            JSONArray authorInfo = null;
            JSONObject imageInfo = null;
            String imageUrl = null;
            String bookTitle = null;
            String bookAuthor = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                ArrayList<Book> books= new ArrayList<Book>();
                for(int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    jsonArrayObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    volumeInfo = jsonArrayObject.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                    bookTitle = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                    authorInfo = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                    bookAuthor = " ";
                    if (authorInfo != null){
                        bookAuthor = authorInfo.getString(0);
                    }
                    //imageInfo = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                    //imageUrl = imageInfo.getString("smallThumbnail");
                    books.add(new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, bookAuthor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this, books);
                populate(bookAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Book Adapter**

```
package com.praveent.booklisting;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book>{

    Context c = null;
    public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0, books);
        c = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        Book currentBook = getItem(position);
        TextView bookTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
        bookTextView.setText(currentBook.getBookName());
        TextView authorTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        authorTextView.setText(currentBook.getAuthorName());
        //ImageView coverImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
        //Picasso.with(c).load(currentBook.getImageURL()).into(coverImageView);
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

**Book Class**

```
package com.praveent.booklisting;

public class Book {

    private String bookName;
    private String authorName;
    private String imageURL;

    public Book(String name, String author){
        bookName = name;
        authorName = author;
        //imageURL = url;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.praveent.booklisting.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_string"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_button" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/cover_image"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/book_author"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share full code of your adapter..

Comment: This is the full adapter. Help me in case I have left anything.

Comment: I guess there is a problem in your `MainActivity` --> `if(scanner.hasNext()){
                    data = scanner.next();
                }`
you need to use `while` **loop** and then `append` data into a `string` instead of `scanner` and then return a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PostExecute Change 
`for(int i = 0; i <=jsonArray.length(); i++)`
to `for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++)`
On list_item.xml change the text color to white

Answer (score -1):

you need to call getCount() in adapter.

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book>{

Context c = null;
ArrayList<Book> bookslist = new ArrayList();
public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
    super(context, 0, books);
    c = context;
    bookslist = books;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bookslist.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    Book currentBook = getItem(position);
    TextView bookTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
    bookTextView.setText(currentBook.getBookName());
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
    authorTextView.setText(currentBook.getAuthorName());
    //ImageView coverImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
    //Picasso.with(c).load(currentBook.getImageURL()).into(coverImageView);
    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you write the function please!

Comment: No, the listView is not yet populating

Answer (score -1):

Change your adapter to this

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

Context c = null;
private List<Book> bookList;

public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
    super(context, 0, books);
    c = context;
    bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    bookList = books;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bookList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Book getItem(int position) {
    return bookList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    Book currentBook = getItem(position);
    TextView bookTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
    bookTextView.setText(currentBook.getBookName());
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
    authorTextView.setText(currentBook.getAuthorName());
    //ImageView coverImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
    //Picasso.with(c).load(currentBook.getImageURL()).into(coverImageView);
    return listItemView;
}

}
```

I checked your code Error is in the AsyncTask onPostExecute method, change your for loop condition to this

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)

It is now working.

Comment: No, the listView is not yet populating

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan i Have edited my answer check the for loop condition